# how get only the full matched string from regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

`/[-+]?\d+([,.]\d+)*/gm`

test:
156,1651,5e6116

if i use the above string for test it is selecting partially.
how to get only the full matched string ?
i'm using the above regex for Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[-+]?\d+([,.]\d+)*$/gm
```

Use anchors `^$` to get only a full match and not partial match.